# how to get realtime JSON from endpoint in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ionic-native

Followed the content of the [url](https://www.djamware.com/post/58fdf9f080aca7414e78a63a/ionic-3-and-angular-4-multi-level-accordion-menu-example) to implement dynamic menu items using JSON file stored under /assets/data. The menu is working fine with stored JSON file. Now I need to dynamically retrieve the JSON of same format in real time from a Salesforce API and display its content. 
Can someone please suggest what changes I need to make here? should the json path in getMainMenu() method be replaced with the actual Saleforce API?

Below is the data-service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the DataServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DataServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello DataServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getMainMenu(){
    return this.http.get('assets/data/mainmenu.json')
    .map((response:Response)=>response.json().Categories);
  }

}
```

and app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { DataServiceProvider } from '../providers/data-service/data-service'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  pages: any[]; //Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
  mainmenu: any[];
  
  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public dataService: DataServiceProvider) {
    this.initializeApp();

    this.dataService.getMainMenu().subscribe((Response)=>{
      this.mainmenu = Response;
      console.log(this.mainmenu);
    });

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
      { title: 'List', component: ListPage }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  toggleSection(i) {
    this.mainmenu[i].open = !this.mainmenu[i].open;
  };

  toggleItem(i,j) {
    this.mainmenu[i].SubCategories[j].open = !this.mainmenu[i].SubCategories[j].open;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will need to update the url in the getMainMenu method to that of your api. There might be some other changes you will need to make, such as adding authentication headers, but if the data coming from the api is the same as whats stored in the assets folder, your component shouldn't care "where" the data comes from.